# Less derogatory term for dump

Tags: expressions, vocabulary, expression-choice, computing

I’m making a (multiple-)photo editing web-app, and there is a certain feature which allows users to sort of “hibernate” their accounts and log out, allowing them to pick up **exactly** where they left off the next time they log in.

The problem is that all this state data is saved in a directory in the user’s account, and right now I’m calling it *muse dump* or *idea dump* (because it is a JSON dump internally), but it sounds and looks horrible.

*Bin, midden*, and *scrap* look absolutely grotesque. *Offload* and *session dump* feels lifeless, dry and obviously not very appealing to the artist minded.

So, how do I describe this operation in two or three words? I definitely cannot use “slang” in this scenario.

Comment: What you describe is not a "dump", it's a "repository".

Comment: Hi user -- going beyond your word question to the purely UX question.  What you're describing is incedibly old fashioned (a button saying "save!")  Just have it continually do that at all times no matter what, like any modenr app or system.

Comment: Exactly @JoeBlow I am more concerned form marketing/present-ability of the app

Comment: what the hell is this "muse" business??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Stack Exchange notifies you: *Draft Saved*. I'd simply go with *Drafts*.

[image: Stack Exchange calls it *Draft Saved*. I'd go with simply, *Drafts*.]

Comment: sure, it's just save draft or save session.

Answer (score 9):

How about *last session* or *session data*?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't explained whether this "name" is something that will necessarily be presented to the users, or just an internal name in the app. If the latter, who cares what it's called?

If the former, why expose some internal working of the application, you should be presenting the user with some guidance on what activity they can perform, such as:

> Continue where you left off.

Or

> Pick up what you were working on last time.

I suspect you are in need of user interface design (UI) assistance, not English help.

Comment: Can't use that because the app lets you edit multiple photos in a workspace. So, *continue* **a-lot-of-past-hibernates** is even more unappealing

Answer (score 2):

You might consider **cache**, as in *muse cache*, *idea cache*, *session cache*.

Here *cache* means something stored away for future use.

Another word is **repository**, which, in computing, is a location where data is stored and managed.

Then there is **archive**, which generally means a long-term or permanent storage for information.

Comment: what the heck is a muse cache dude??

Comment: In computing, _cache_ has a connotation of being temporary and disposable.  On the other hand, _repository_ and _archive_ sound too permanent

Comment: This word would be chosen for the users' benefit, as it shows up in the user interface. Since that's a "real world" interface, It can convey the common meaning of the word, and it doesn't have to carry the technical meaning that code developers use. But that's something the OP has to decide.

Answer (score 2):

Joe Blow is right. The default behavior should simply be that it reopens all windows just as they were when the app was closed.

if you want to characterize an unfinished project, you might call it a work-in-progress, although draft is also good.

You didn't ask, but I'd suggest that your proposed name "Muse Dump" has two problems. "Dump" may be crude and inaccurate, but "Muse" is pretentious and inaccurate. Keep it simple, like "Saved Work" or something. Good luck!